# Delete from a character above current cursor until cursor position?

Tags: vim

Say I have:

```
void SomeFunc () 
{
    //stuff
}
```

If my cursor is where the { is, how can I "delete up to )" ?

In other words, how can I get :

```
void SomeFunc (){
    //stuff
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
kJ
```

- `k`: move up a line
- `J`: join next line.

Comment: you left out a step: vim leaves a space before the curly brace.